# SQL Has Many association search (key, value)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this two tables :

```
ads(id, title)

values(id, key, value, ad_id)
```

I'd like to have all 'ad' that have multiple combination of key/value

```
ads(1, 'Hello #1')
ads(2, 'Hello #2')
ads(3, 'Hello #3')
ads(4, 'Hello #4')

values(1, 'brand', 'BMW', 1)
values(2, 'model', 'serie 1', 1)
values(3, 'brand', 'BMW', 2)
values(3, 'model', 'serie 2', 2)
```

if a user search for value 'BMW' and 'Serie 1', he should have only ad with id 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method of doing this uses conditional aggregation:

```
select ad_id
from values v
where key = 'brand' and value = 'BMW' or
      key = 'model' and value = 'serie 1'
group by ad_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

The `where` clause has the `key`/`value` pairs connected with `or`.  The `having` clause has a count to check that all match.

Note:  `values` and `key` are a reserved words in MySQL, so it is a poor choice for a table or column name.  Similarly, `value` is allowed, but it would be better to have a different name.  I haven't escaped these values, because I assume they are really something different in your actual data.